# Integrating Survey Responses in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, contactbuilder, survey

I recently created a Survey in the Sales Cloud, but I want to be able to get the responses in the Marketing Cloud to add them to a journey and better manipulate this data. I was able to create a synchronized data source but only with the Survey Invitation entity (**MC -> Audience Builder -> Contact Builder -> Data Sources -> Synchronized -> Set Up Object**), but as I mentioned before I need the Survey Question Responses entity ([Salesforce Standard Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_surveyquestionresponse.htm)). How can I set up a synchronized data extension with the Survey Question Responses Object?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that Survey object is not available in Data Sources, then you can try using an [Import Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_import_activity.htm&type=5) to import the Salesforce Object.

> If your account is integrated with a Salesforce account, use an import
>   activity to create and populate a data extension with the data from a
>   Salesforce object or report.

**Email Studio > Email > Interactions > Activities > Import > Create**

Under File Location, select the Salesforce Object & Reports. You must be logged in as an integrated user.

[image: Import Salesforce Object]

Comment: just tried this and the objects were mapped into a data extension, but they did not appear in contact builder as data sources. I guess this might work better for this particular case, but for future reference how can I make the objects appear as data sources?

Comment: just talked to support, seems to be a permission sets issue. I have not tried solving it, but this answer provides a good alternative

Comment: Is the only way is the retrieve the data through the interactions? Can the data be retrieved automated through this route or is this a one off.

Comment: @RobSource, throw it in Automation Studio and it is automated. Best bet is to sync it through synchronized data extensions and just write a SQL query.